# How to big screen (42"-50") hardware and programming in android?

Tags: android, windows, kiosk, television

I want to make an information desk program for a hospital. 2000 people will touch this system daily. I fed up withsearching about how to do this system. :( There is not any android big tablet in turkey. In the end i come to 3 options about `hardware structure`.

1. Buying an android tv an progrramming it. This is easy way to do just i ll program an android sytem. But is any android tv which is resistant to 2000 touch daily????
2. Buying a monitor and android 7" tablet (root structured) and mirroring app tablet to monitor with using hdmi to mini usb cable. But tablet program screen will be bigger right? and isnt that bad idea coz i cannot use 42" whole screen correctly right?
3. Buying a kiosk which is just windows options in turkey :( So i dont want to code in .net. So if i have to i ll make in the and.

Please help me about how to make this system. What is your idea?

Comment: Best Option, Android TV Programming or build app for android system and take android STB and install your app to use it. e.g. In real life, android user can obviously storks keys in TV more the 2000+.

Comment: @Naitik so android tv is strong enough for 2000 times touching daily? Do you know more about resistance capasity of android tv screen for more touches. I dont want touchable screen is crashed by more touches

Comment: Android TV isn't likely to be a good option because you still need a touch panel on the display, and the STB would need USB inputs.

Comment: @KitGrose i think i can find touchable android tv isnt it?

Comment: Android TV is a software platform, mostly focused on controlling Android with a remote control from a distance. Regular Android is the platform that is best suited to touch kiosks, but you'll need to find a suitable hardware vendor first (my experience with kiosks are all Windows so I don't know how well the hardware is supported by Android).

Comment: @KitGrose Should i make an app in windows? i can make it. can you suggest me to do in windows?

Comment: In Windows you'd use UWP (or any number of third party UI frameworks), and use any HID touch device, which has built in driver support in Windows 7+. You can get infrared frames that you mount in front of existing display panels or you can get panels with built-in touch. For hospitals it's often worth considering a projected capacitive touch panel (like the ones from Zytronic) behind glass so you can use harsh cleaners without breaking the panel, but they're not particularly cheap (especially if you need multitouch)